# Right destroy of objects in JavaScript from constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, destroy

Example for my problem:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function Marker(opts) {
    opts = opts || {};
    this.text = opts.text || 'Hello!';
    this.node = null;
    this.init();
};

Marker.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.node = document.createElement('div');
        this.node.innerHTML = this.text;
        document.body.appendChild(this.node);
    },
    destroy: function() {
        if ( this.node && this.node.parentNode )
            this.node.parentNode.removeChild(this.node);

        for (var i in this)
            if ( this.hasOwnProperty(i) )
                delete this[i];

        // this.constructor = null; // :-(
        // this = null; // :-(
        // H O W ?
    }
};

var first = new Marker({ text: 'first' });

alert( first instanceof Marker );
first.destroy();
alert( first instanceof Marker ); // want false
```

How should I update method `.destroy()`, if I want to see false in second message box?
Solution must be croossbrowsing, without using **proto**.

Comment: `first = null`, that's your only option (or at least it makes most sense in this context).

Comment: Apart from assigning `first` a different value, you have no other options not involving mangling with prototypes, since [ECMAScript](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.5.3) says `instanceof` relies on the prototype comparison.

Answer (score 0):

There no way to replace this with null but you may add field destroyed to prototype and check exits by function exist: `Marker.prototype.exist=function(){ !this.destroyed; }`

```
destroy=function(){
  ...
  this.destroyed=true;
}
```